# Apportable no visible @interface for 'NSData' declares the selector 'initWithBase64EncodedString:options:'

Tags: ios, apportable

I get this error in appportable when trying to port a xcode project to android I tried using  some files like NSDataAdditions.h but it doesnt have the options argument in any of the functions any help?

Answer (score 0):

we currently do not have that function available publicly.

You can follow progress on that [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/apportable-discuss/initwithbase64encodedstring%7Csort%3arelevance%7Cspell%3atrue/apportable-discuss/DIPPc3HWgow/M2_9mHDYLP8J).